# PHP - ADO recordsets

Tags: php, com, ado

I am referencing a COM component from PHP. This COM component returns records using ADO.

I am assuming I will need to reference ADO in PHP for this to function. 
How do I do this?

Secondly (related to the first question) I have run accross ADODB abstraction libraries, however these seem to mostly deal with queries and handle the ADO internally. How do I get the returned ADO recordset into a PHP friendly array, and likewise pass in an ADO array to the COM object?

Thank you,
Josh

Comment: Are you on a Windows system as COM is Windows only

Comment: Yes, I am on a windows system for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$con = new COM('ADODB.Connection');
$con->ConnectionString = 'my connect string here';

$cmd = new COM('ADODB.Command');
....
```

when calling methods that have "optional" parameters use the following to skip them:

```
new VARIANT(VT_UNKNOWN);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/

This site contains a lot of the base ADO classes and enums that you'll need. But I would recommend having a ADO book. Then its mainly a using those examples while changing . to -> when referencing COM object properties and methods.